# Calderon Zygmund decomposition - Empty set

Tags: harmonic-analysis, singular-integrals

The statement of the Calderon-Zygmund decomposition as given in Duoandikoetxea's book is the following.

For $f$ integrable on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and non-negative and given $\lambda>0$, there exist a sequence $\{Q_j\}$ of disjoint dyadic cubes such that

1. $f(x) \leq \lambda$ for almost every $x \notin \cup Q_j$
2. $|\cup Q_j|\leq \frac{\lVert f \rVert_1}{\lambda}$
3. For each $j$, $\lambda < \frac{1}{|Q_j|} \int_{Q_j} fdx<2^n\lambda$.

In the proof, you need to consider the case when no such cubes exist. In Grafakos's proof of the theorem, he makes a note of the fact that in some cases the set $\cup Q_j$ is empty. In this case, I do not see how the the third requirement is true. If you have the empty sequence is this vacuously true? If you have the empty sequence then $\frac{1}{|Q_j|} \to \infty$ so how can 3 be true?

Comment: If you have an empty sequence of cubes, (3) is vacuously true.

Comment: How come? If $Q_i$ is one of the cubes in the sequence $\{Q_j\}$ then all that tells you is that $Q_i=\emptyset$ not that there is some element in $\emptyset$.

Comment: Well, you need to choose $\{Q_j\}_{j \in J}$ with a countable (possibly empty) set J. At least that is one way to fix the issue.